# How to get ONLY the commit messages between 2 svn revisions?

Tags: svn

I know how to get the svn log between 2 revisions, but for my script I just need the messages people wrote while commitng-
svn commit -m "message"

I know i can svn log -r rev1:rev2 but this also gives me the changes in the files which I dont want.

How can I get only the "message" part of all the commits between the 2 revisions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
svn.exe log -r r1:r3 --xml
```

Output fragment is:

```
<log>
<logentry revision="1">
<author>User1</author>
<date>2015-08-31T10:17:24.735773Z</date>
<msg>your_message</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Parse the resulting xml for `<msg>your_message</msg>` tag in all of     `<logentry>...</logentry>` elements of `<log>` root.

Read more about log in [doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) - where is no option to filter the output except --verbose and --quiet.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `svn log -r<A>:<B> <REPO_URL>` it should output for each revision:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r<Revision> | <Author> | <Date> <Time> <TZ>  | <lines changed>

commit Message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

If you are using **-v** it will put the modified files into the list as well, if you use **-q**, it will output only the line with the revision